# assign @chageset not available in eex template in Phoenix when using HAML

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm following the Programming Phoenix book but using HAML as the template engine. When rendering the new temmplate to create new users I'm getting this error:

`assign @chageset not available in eex template.`

I'm using Chris Mccord's [Phoenix_HAML](https://github.com/chrismccord/phoenix_haml) and have configured everything there.

The controller is exactly as described in the book:

```
defmodule Rumbl.UserController do
    use Rumbl.Web, :controller

     def index(conn, _params) do
       users = Repo.all(Rumbl.User)
       render conn, "index.html", users: users
     end

     def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
      user = Repo.get(Rumbl.User, id)
      render conn, "show.html", user: user
    end

    alias Rumbl.User

    def new(conn, _params) do
      changeset = User.changeset(%User{})
     render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
    end
  end
```

And the template

```
%h1 New User
  = form_for @chageset, user_path(@conn, :create), fn f ->
    %div.form-group
     = text_input f, :name, placeholder: "Name", class: "form-control"
    %div.form-group
     = text_input f, :username, placeholder: "Username", class: "form-control"
    %div.form-group
     = password_input f, :password, placeholder: "Password", class: "form-control"
    = submit "Create User", class: "btn btn-primary"
 - end
```

What is missing here?

Comment: Typo in `@chageset`?

Comment: Unbeliavable... Sorry for the trouble... It was the typo...

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem

I get

```
(EEx.SyntaxError) lib/hello_web/templates/user/form.html.haml:1: 
    unexpected end of string, expected a closing '<% end %>'
    (eex) lib/eex/compiler.ex:91: EEx.Compiler.generate_buffer/4
    (eex) lib/eex/compiler.ex:45: EEx.Compiler.generate_buffer/4
```

with the following form.html.haml:

```
= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f ->
  = if @changeset.action do
  .alert.alert-danger
    %p Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below.
  .form-group
    = label f, :name, class: "control-label"
    = text_input f, :name, class: "form-control"
    = error_tag f, :name
  .form-group
    = label f, :email, class: "control-label"
    = text_input f, :email, class: "form-control"
    = error_tag f, :email
  .form-group
    = label f, :bio, class: "control-label"
    = text_input f, :bio, class: "form-control"
    = error_tag f, :bio
  .form-group
    = label f, :number_of_pets, class: "control-label"
    = number_input f, :number_of_pets, class: "form-control"
    = error_tag f, :number_of_pets
  .form-group
    = submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Simple HAML files work fine.